# call some methods in one line

Tags: javascript

I build a objects source in JavaScript.
Is there any way to call some methods in one line like this:

```
var x = new object("aaa").method_a().method_b().method_c();
```

Comment: You can also do what you suggest, as long as they all return the method (`return this;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to chain function call's  you need to return `this` from your functions

```
function method_a(){
  // do something
  return this;
}
```

Same for other functions -

then you can do `var x = new object("aaa").method_a().method_b().method_c();`

Answer (score 2):

The way to do that is making each method to return the object itself. For example:

```
function Person() {};

Person.prototype.setName=function(n){
    this.name=n;
    return this;
}

Person.prototype.setAge=function(a) {
    this.age=a;
    return this;
}

var p= new Person().setName("John").setAge(20);
```

The obvious gotcha is you cannot do that if the method has to return any other value (you can do it with setters but not with getters)

Answer (score 0):

If your object doesn't support a fluid interface you can always wrap that functionality on top of it:

```
function FluidWrapper(obj)
{
  var o = {};

  for (var p in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[p] == 'function') {
      o[p] = function(method) {
        return function() {
          obj[method].apply(obj, [].slice.call(arguments, 0));
          return o;
        };
      }(p);
    }
  }

  return o;
}

var x = new object("aaa");
FluidWrapper(x).method_a().method_b().method_c();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/dularenu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

While Mohammad Adil's answer is the most common scenario, i feel that the possibilities haven't been explored properly.

A function returns a value. In JavaScript you can call methods on any value except null and undefined. This means that this is perfectly acceptable:

```
var x = 987654321;
var y = x.toString().split('').sort().join('0');
```

In this scenario,

- the `toString()` method was called on a Number who's internal value is `987654321` and returns a string.
- the `split('')` method was called on a String who's internal value is `'987654321'` and returns an Array.
- the `sort()` method was called on an Array holding the following values:`['9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2','1']` and returns the same Array (but sorted).
- The `join('0')` method was called on the same Array, but holding the values `['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']` and returns a string.
- finally, after all these operations, `y` contains the value `'10203040506070809'`;

So it is not necessary for the object the chained methods act on to be the same, as long as you are aware at every step of what that object is.

When you have a method called on an object, inside that method `this` will refer to the object. So if you `return this;`, then another method of that object can be called afterwards.

---

It is important to note that sometimes you want to return a new object of the same type rather than change the object and return it. Both work equally well when chaining, but the results are different when not. Consider the following jQuery example:

```
var divs = $('div'); // all divs on the page
var marked = divs.filter('.marked'); // all marked divs on the page
marked.css('color', 'red'); // make marked divs red
```

Because the [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method returns a new jQuery object, the initial divs variable still contains all the divs on the page. If the filter method were to eliminate things from the jQuery object it was called on and return it, then divs would point to the same object as marked and therefore would no longer have all divs on the page.
From a chaining perspective, nothing changes between the two potential implementations (except for some throw-away objects):

```
$('div').filter('.marked').css('color', 'red');
```